# Python list is behaving weird

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wanted to clean a list by its length, removing small words.

```
    def is_word_min_than(number, word):
    if len(word) > number:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def filtrate_valid_words(query):
    min_len_number = 3
    for word in query:
        if is_word_min_than(min_len_number, word):
            query.remove(word)
    return query

filtrate_valid_words(['tacos',',','kkk'])
```

My last value was in the returned query, it hadnt to be there. I came up with the idea that this was happening because I was modifying the object I was iterating.

So I cloned my first list.

```
    def is_word_min_than(number, word):
    if len(word) > number:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def filtrate_valid_words(query):
    min_len_number = 3
    original_query = query
    for word in original_query:
        if is_word_min_than(min_len_number, word):
            query.remove(word)
    return query

filtrate_valid_words(['tacos',',','kkk'])
```

Same thing was happening, i dont know why.
Anyway, I used the first solution that came to my mind.

```
    def is_word_min_than(number, word):
    if len(word) > number:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def filtrate_valid_words(query):
    min_len_number = 3
    words_to_delete = []
    for word in query:
        if is_word_min_than(min_len_number, word):
            words_to_delete.append(word)
    for word in words_to_delete:
        query.remove(word)
    return query
```

Now is working but Im just curious about why that happened.
Thank you, I hope is not something really dumb. And if is that I would not be surprised, I have to go to sleep.

Comment: *I have to go to sleep*??

Comment: @Lara: bad style to say "please solve my problem, I will sleep now."

Comment: Yes, maybe I cant see the obvious because Im tired.

Comment: Y said I have solved, Im just curious.

Comment: As Yossi mentions in his answer you haven't really cloned `query`, you've simply bound the same list object to a new name, so you can now refer to that object with `query` or `original_query`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python and SO member Ned Batchelder's excellent article [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not support removing elements from list being iterated. This is exactly what happens in your first solution.

You might say that you copied the `list` in `original_query = query`, but this not the case. This line only copies the reference which does not make and difference.

Your first solution will work if you will actually make a copy of your input

```
original_query = list(query)
```

Or just use one-liner which is more efficient and readable

```
filtered = [word for word in query if len(word) > 3]
```